# Unable to access Jupyter notebook on port 8888 with this port open

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

I want to run a Jupyter notebook an an Azure vm.  I launch the notebook with:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888 --ip=127.0.0.1
```

Next, I verify the process is listening on port 8888.

```
sudo netstat -pant | grep "LISTEN"
```

Which returns:

```
tcp   0  0 127.0.0.1:8888   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN     22451/python
```

I can make this conntection:

```
wget -vvv http://127.0.0.1
```

Returning:

```
--2019-06-27 17:27:34--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3700 (3.6K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[============================================================================================================>] 3,700       --.-K/s   in 0s

2019-06-27 17:27:34 (642 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [3700/3700]
```

From the Azure portal, I have:

[image: Azure Inbound/Outbound Security Rules]

Firefox says it is unable to connect.  On another Firefox tab at: `http://127.0.0.0.1:80` I get the Apache Server test page.

How do I get to the Jupyter notebook page on port 8888?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address... In jupyter notebook command, use 0.0.0.0 in --ip and with in firefox, use your public IP and 8888 port.

Comment: Thanks @MB11--that worked!

Comment: Please add it as an answer as it will help other who have the same requirement.